# Collect information by the specific name from different data

Tags: r, csv

I have some csv files with the data. I loaded them:

```
tbl = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
list_of_data = lapply(tbl, read.csv)
```

How the data looks like:

First csv:

```
              Exp1  Exp2  Exp3
Morgan.1       11    23    22
Catrine.2      14    33    55
Markus.1       ger   32    12
```

Second csv:

```
              Exp1  Exp2  Exp3
Morgan.2       17    nex   23
Catrine.1      15    23    15
Markus.7       11    ger   11
```

I would like to make a single csv file of those data. How to find a data for Morgan (ignore something what's after the dot) in different csv files and put them in one file.

Prefered output:

```
           Exp1  Exp2  Exp3  Exp1  Exp2  Exp3
Morgan     17    nex   23    11    23    22
Catrine    14    33    55    15    23    15
```

I am pretty sure that I have to make a loop to collect all of the data but let me know how to do it for a single name etc.

That's what I did to get a list of all of the "names" in one table:

```
all_data = do.call(rbind.fill, list_of_data)
data_rd <- subset(transform(all_data, X = sub("\\..*", "", X)), 
       !duplicated(X))
```

Comment: Which language is this?

Comment: I wanted to select R but no idea why it didn't appear. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

First I create a single data.frame using `` `do.call(rbind,...) ``

```
dt1 = read.table(text='             Exp1  Exp2  Exp3
Morgan.1       11    23    22
Catrine.2      14    33    55
Markus.1       ger   32    12',header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)


dt2 = read.table(text='Exp1  Exp2  Exp3
Morgan.2       17    nex   23
Catrine.1      15    23    15
Markus.7       11    ger   11',header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

DT = do.call(rbind,list(dt1,dt2))
```

Then I extract "morgan" rows using some regular expressions on row.name:

```
DT[grep('Morgan',rownames(DT)),]

         Exp1 Exp2 Exp3
Morgan.1   11   23   22
Morgan.2   17  nex   23
```

Comment: That's one solution but I prefer to have it in another order like in one row all of the data specific for the "Morgan".

Comment: @Rechlay, please then update your question with the _desired output_, not just "put them in one file".

Comment: @Rechlay come on! You ask a lot and you don't do anything in your side :) ( The wrong way to learn) . That's said, apply `unlist` in my previous result to get a vector.

Comment: I try to do something but I don't how should I start to learn R. It's not that easy for a beginner. I spend few hours per day reading books about R and I see that's useless. Anyway, thanks for helping me. Updated my question.